# Whitelisting Nested Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a params hash with the following structure (it was built using fields_for)

```
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
    "daily_log"=>
      {"id"=>"1",
       "entries_attributes"=>
          {"0"=>
              {"count"=>"",
               "hours"=>"",
               "minutes"=>"",
              }
          }
       },
    "controller"=>"entries",
    "action"=>"create"}
```

I'm trying to create a an `entries_attributes_params` method which should just return a whitelisted version of `params['daily_log']['entries_attributes']`. Unfortunately, this keeps coming back as `{}` when I call the method.

The following works

```
def entries_attributes_params`
   params[:daily_log][:entries_attributes].permit!
end
```

But i want to avoid using `permit!`.  So I tried the following:

```
def entries_attributes_params
    params[:daily_log][:entries_attributes].permit(:count, :hours, :minutes)
end
```

This doesn't work.  I get `{}` back.

I tried wrapping the attributes I pass into `permit` with `[]`, but that doesn't work.

```
...permit([...attributes...])
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def entries_attributes_params
  params_hash = params.require(:daily_log).permit(:id, entries_attributes: [:count, :hours, :minutes])
  params_hash[:entries_attributes]
end
```

Comment: I get the following error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: entries_attributes)

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab it.  Your revised code got me partially there.  The above code will return the wrong part of the hash, so the full answer is a little more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The key is to recognize that `params.permit ...` doesn't actually change the main params hash.  It creates a new object.  Combining this idea with K M's solution below gives the full answer:

```
def entries_attributes_params
  p = params.require(:daily_log).permit(:id, entries_attributes: [:count, :hours, :minutes])
  p[:entries_attributes]
end
```